# Why does Maven create artifact checksums?

Tags: maven

Seeing as JAR files are a subset of ZIP files, and ZIP files include a checksum for all entries, why does Maven add an additional checksum on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Maven artifacts are JARs/ZIPs.  There are also POMs, SWFs and many other file types that can be uploaded to repositories from various plugins.

Examples:

[FlexMojos plugin](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/) generates SWF (flash player) files.

[Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) can generate TAR files.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a checksum is to validate the file content. The checksum of your downloaded file should match the checksum in the repository. Maven Central also encourages authors to digitally sign the files they upload, providing an additional layer of trust in the repository artefacts.

Comment: Signature-aside, what's the point? ZIP files already checksum their content. Why do it twice?

Comment: It is not for ensuring internal integrity but to be able to compare two artifacts quickly without having to look at each and every byte.